# Separate Data Access Layers for Distributed Compute

Tags: spring, apache-spark, distributed-computing, data-access-layer

**Overview**

Currently my product maintains a DAL that is separated from business logic and exposed via a set of services where each service generally corresponds to an element i.e. `Car` objects are accessed via the `CarService`. These services are powered through Spring Data `Repositories` and access data (models) stored in both `PostgreSQL` and `Elasticsearch`.

We are now processing more and more data (documents in, our models out or documents in, clustering, models out) and have realized that computation has become a bottleneck. To overcome this we are evaluating Spark or Apache Beam to distribute the computation horizontally which would solve the problem.

**Problem**

After looking into the Spark (and Beam) frameworks I have found that they generally provide their own integration (or plugin) for reading/writing from/to datasources, which in and of itself is great. The problem for me is that I can't find anyway for these frameworks to support distributed reading/writing through our current set of services. Spark requires `RDD` and Beam requires `PCollection` and I'd rather not support 2 methods of reading/writing from our datastores to accommodate.

**My Question**

Has anyone encountered this before? What was your strategy?

Did you go ahead and support 2 types of DAL? If so, were there any caveats with this especially with regards to the ongoing maintenance of the code?

Comment: You want to read /write inside apache spark using your service ? could you please explain littile , what you want to achive at the end ?

Answer (score 3):

In software engineering, multi-tier architecture is a client-server architecture in which, the presentation, the application processing and the data management are logically separate processes, crosscutting concern or logical separation helps for performance, scalability and maintenance.

keep in mind that  tiers are at logical levels which means that may or may not be many physical layers.

If you are going with Image 1 then no need new DAO layers but in Image 2  , i will suggest create separate project and use EAI pattern to communicate both projects

**Image 1:**

[image]

In image 1 you can process data and keep into database and use same DAO layer to get data

**Image 2:**

[image]

In image 2 You can create separate layer where you have to submit your jobs and collect results  directly into your spring code .

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html

**Apacge Spark or Bigdata has diffrent archetecture styles ,plesae read following links .**

1. http://lambda-architecture.net/
2. http://milinda.pathirage.org/kappa-architecture.com/
3. https://mapr.com/solutions/zeta-enterprise-architecture/
4. [What are the differences between kappa-architecture and lambda-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967295/what-are-the-differences-between-kappa-architecture-and-lambda-architecture)